segmentation fault c++ vs code windows не могу понять причину
написала буквально простейшую программу. При этом не только вс код буянит, но еще и в терминале программа не запускается.  я даже не знаю где копать. компилятор установлен с другими проектами проблем не было
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}

CMakePresets.json
{
    "version": 8,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "pacman",
            "displayName": "Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - x86_amd64",
            "description": "Using compilers for Visual Studio 17 2022 (x86_x64 architecture)",
            "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
            "toolset": "host=x86",
            "architecture": "x64",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX": "${sourceDir}/out/install/",
                "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl.exe",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl.exe"
            }
        }
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "pacman",
            "displayName": "Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - x86_amd64",
            "configurePreset": "pacman"
        }
    ]
}

добавляю. Почему-то программа пытается оформить вывод не через терминал, а через другое приложение. написала CMakePresets.json и слава богу, заработало. Но для других прог написание файла не требовалось. Они все лежат в одной папке вместе с текущими проектами. А текущие проги без этого файла не запускаются. Почему так? И почему у меня вывод автоматически пытается сработать через Inkscape?

miDebuggerPath у вас туда прописан компилятор, а не отладчик
